# Hibernate Lazy loading not work in OneToOne relation

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

In my company we migrated one old app from Hibernate 2 to Hibernate 4.
My task was to move all xml entities to annotations. After moving it lazy loading in OneToOne relationship stop working.

entity a xml:

```
<id name="entityAid" type="integer" column="entityAid_id">
<one-to-one name="entityB" entity-name="EntityB"
        property-ref="entityA" />
```

entity b xml:

```
<property name="entityAid" type="integer" column="entityA_id" />
<many-to-one name="entityA" column="entityA_id" entity-name="EntityA" update="false" insert="false" />
```

I moved it with code:

entity a

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entityA")
 private EntityB storageRatecard;
```

entity b

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "entityA_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private EntityA entityA;
```

Now when I run app lazy loading not work but worked on xml conf. I found:

[Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

but nothing helps.(I cant use bytecode instrumentation)

What I am doing wrong? Why with xml everything is ok and with annotations no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What work for mi is Lazy one-to-one inverse relationships.

I read about this [here](http://justonjava.blogspot.com/2010/09/lazy-one-to-one-and-one-to-many.html) (it is also a good tutorial how to use it). I hope it will help some one as it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entityA")
private EntityB storageRatecard;
```

to :

```
@OneTOMany(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entityA")
private List<EntityB> storageRatecard;
```

Or if you want to make one to one bidirectional relationship than:

From:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "entityA_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private EntityA entityA;
```

to:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "entityA_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private EntityA entityA;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.I need to have one to one bidirectional relationship. I try yours solution earlier but it not help.

Comment: @ognistysztorm The main idea is to have `@OneToOne` annotations on both parameters or `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`

Comment: I tried use OneToOne instead ManyToOne but as I wrote lazy loading still not works. I cant understand why lazy loading  work when I am using hbk.xml?

Comment: It's because @OneToOne lazzy works little bit diferently [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1445694/4327527)

Answer (score 0):

JPA eager loads single ended association. Check the following link for more details:
[JPA default fetch type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127831/jpa-default-fetch-type)